# MSSQL Management Studio - Use to use statements

Tags: sql-server

I want to use two use statements and my current two use statements will not work because the second one would override the first one. How do I fix it?

```
While exists (Select name from #db)
  Begin
    select @name = min(name) from #db

    set @tsql = 'use '+@name+' '+

     'USE msdb
      EXEC sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = ''Blah blah blah'',
      ----'    
  End
```

I want to send email notifications to an email address when something happens after a query is run. The only way I see to use the `sp_send_dbmail` is with the `Use msdb` command. However, if I use two `use` statements, the second one would override the first.

Comment: Totally unclear where your problem is. Better example, please.

Comment: Define "fix it".  Yes, later settings override earlier ones.  That's the correct behavior, so what does *fixing* that mean?

Comment: do you need the `USE`, can't you append the database name to your queries?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Look at my update

Comment: @TomTom Look at my update

Comment: Still totally unclear why you need to use two USE statements, but in any event, there's a simple fix to your problem as stated in @Rory's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the database name in the EXEC statement, e.g.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Adventure Works Administrator',
    @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
    @body = 'The stored procedure finished successfully.',
    @subject = 'Automated Success Message' ;
```

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

You can also add a proc in your own db that calls this, so callers don't need to know the name of the dbmail profile etc. e.g.

```
create proc dbo.usp_send_email 
      @recipients nvarchar(max)
    , @body nvarchar(max)
    , @subject nvarchar(max)
as

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'Your Standard Profile',
        @recipients = @recipients,
        @body = @body,
        @subject = @subject;

go
```

The above shows you don't need to use `USE`. But for interest's sake, regarding the `USE` statement, you can't use `EXEC` or `sp_executeSql` to change the current connection's database because they're executed in a different context. So for instance this gives slightly surprising output:

```
use master
exec ('use msdb')
print db_name()  -- outputs 'master'
exec sp_executeSql N'use msdb;'
print db_name()  -- outputs 'master'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear, but I'm guessing that you're building a SQL statement to execute using sp_ExecuteSql. And that the SQL statement needs to run on a different database.

Well, you can do something like this:

```
set @tsql = 'use @name; ' + <do some code here>

exec sp_ExecuteSql @tsql

set @tsql = 'use <some other db>; ' + <do some other code here>

exec sp_ExecuteSql @tsql
```

or even this will work, if for whatever reason, calling exec sp_ExecuteSql twice is too much of a burden for you:

```
set @tsql = 'use @name; ' + <do some code here> + '; use <some other db>; ' + <do some other code here>

exec sp_ExecuteSql @tsql
```